# Extent of proof for provenance of funds - Sponsor of UK Vistor Visa

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am a UK citizen living in Colombia and intend to return to home with my Colombian girlfriend for a month over Christmas to visit family.

My girlfriend is a student and from a modest Colombian background, hence she has basically no money in her bank account or an income. I am going to act as her sponsor, covering the costs for the entire trip.

My financial situation is complex with money spread across multiple bank and investment accounts (the multiple accounts is for getting the best interest rates, hence not dodgy, I used to be a financial advisor). This money came from 2 main sources: income in previous jobs and inheritance.

I have one main bank account that covers the cost of the trip by a considerable margin.

My questions are:

1. Do I have to provide documents for all of my (10+) accounts? Or given that the main account has more than enough to cover it, will that suffice?
2. The inheritance and income money has been in my accounts for over a year. Do I need to provide proof of provenance for these amounts? Or will bank statements for the past 6 months suffice?
3. Do the bank statements need to be originals? All my accounts are paperless and hence I only have pdf's unless I specifically request them from the bank (costly and time consuming for all 10+ accounts)

For context on question 2: my employment income savings have been in my account for 2 years so do I need to go back and dig out tax returns / pay slips for that far back?

Many thanks

Update - this is not a duplicate. I have read the potential duplicate article that was flagged multiple times and it doens't answer my specific questions.

Comment: @blackhaj From personal experience of two successful applications: Q1 - you don’t need to provide everything. I supplied 6 months’ worth of current account statements and one savings account statement showing a balance considerably more than the stated cost of the trip. Q2 - I supplied payslips for the previous 6 months, and my end of tax year pay statement showing total income for the latest tax year. Q3 originals are required https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf